# Codename One Retrieve Logs After Crash

Tags: ios, crash, codenameone

Is there a way to retrieve logs after a crash with codename one? I have a process that does a large data conversion and my app crashes/closes while trying to complete it, only on iPhone.

I do have premium/crash protection on, but I don't get an email from this. I'm wondering if I can look at the logs and not have them wiped by closing/re-opening the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the app appends to the logs, you can add a "Send Logs to developer" button or hidden feature and invoke `Log.sendLogAsync()` to email the log to you.

If this doesn't include what you need I would also suggest including the [native logging cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html) since it might include information about the crash.

Comment: The problem was that I was running the app out of memory - so it makes sense that the crash protection wouldn't be able to send the email.

And to see where it failed, instead of logging to the built in logger, I just wrote to a storage file so that I could see how far it got.